# How to get the user downloads folder location with Python

Tags: application-development, python, wget

So, I'm developing a simple download manager powered by Wget, [EasyDownloader][1], which I'm using for learning Python, and I have a problem.

I want to save files at the Downloads folder, but it's not called 'Downloads' in computers without Ubuntu in English. So, I would like to know if there's a downloads path or something simmilar in Ubuntu?

Comment: Please do ask only one thing per question, otherwise it makes it more difficult to answer. Feel free to open a separate question for your other issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's how you can get the downloads folder for any user in Python:

Gtk2:

```
import glib
downloads_dir = glib.get_user_special_dir(glib.USER_DIRECTORY_DOWNLOAD)
```

Gtk3:

```
from gi.repository import GLib
downloads_dir = GLib.get_user_special_dir(GLib.UserDirectory.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOAD)
```

Documentation:

- [get_user_special_dir()](http://developer.gnome.org/pygobject/stable/glib-functions.html#function-glib--get-user-special-dir) function
- [Special dir constants](http://developer.gnome.org/pygobject/stable/glib-constants.html#glib-user-directory-constants)

Comment: Thanks, now I don't need my "Downloads" symbolic link! :P